# Fastest way to execute applying a function to a large data set

Tags: perl, function, module, performance

I am wondering what is the fastest way (in terms of execution time) to apply a functional transformation to every value in in a data set (or a column vector).  The following code complies, and I am wondering whether it can be made to be more efficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;
use String::Nysiis qw(nysiis);

open( my $l,  '<', 'Strings.txt' )          or die "Can't open locations: $!";
open( my $o,  '>', 'NYSIIS.txt' )          or die "Can't open locations: $!";

while ( my $line = <$l> ) {
  my $transform = nysiis($line);
  print "$line,$transform,\n" ;
  print( $o ("$line,$transform"),"\n" );

}
close $o;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, just micros.

- Don't autoflush.
- Load the entire file into memory.
- Don't chomp if `nysiis` doesn't care about the newline.
- Don't print twice. Use `tee` instead. (Good advice period.)

You could get gains by parallelising.

Comment: Thank you!  I took out the autoflush and the chomp.  If I may please ask, is tee from the IO::Tee package or do I have the wrong tee?  Also, how would loading the entire file into memory look?  Would that be with a push?  As in while (my $line = <$l>) { push(@dataset_array, $line); }  And then would I do something like while(scalar(@dataset_array)){ in place of the current while loop?

Comment: @user2096518 How could it possibly be faster to do the same thing plus one more thing? No, what ikegami presumably refers to is `my @lines = <$l>`; for my $line (@lines)`

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of `local $/; my $file = <$l>;`, but then you have to split that into lines. I'm not sure if line at time, what I meant, or what @TLP though I meant is faster.

Comment: TLP: I'm sorry but I'm not following what you are saying. . . . For example, I'm not following for my $line (@lines)' because I don't see what ' is for, why the { is removed, and what @lines is for.  I hope it is ok I asked that.  I do not mean to upset you.  I also do not follow the syntax for tee . . .

Comment: ikegami: What about the for loop?  And as I wrote to TLP,  I hope it is ok I asked that. I do not mean to upset you. I also do not follow the syntax for tee . .

Comment: And like I said earlier, "I'm not sure [which of the three] is faster."

Comment: ikegami: I don't know exactly which 3 you mean.  And I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the syntax for any of them that I had not originally coded.  Is local $/; my $file = <$l>; in place of the for loop altogether?  That does not make sense to me.  What do you mean by parallelising?

Comment: "Actually, I was thinking of `local $/; my $file = <$l>;`, but then you have to split that into lines."